# Multi-Platform Amazon-AWS Development

Tags: linux, windows, macos, amazon-web-services, monodevelop

I am looking to develop an application which communicates with Amazon S3 Buckets and Amazon EC2 Instances. I need to develop it for multiple platforms, and I have seen that developing via Mono seems to be the popular answer. Is there a way to use the AWS SDK (.NET or Java) in Mono without excluding any of the platforms (Windows, Mac OSX, and Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are building API's to access your application that are not language specific (i.e. they require client the are only available in a particular language), clients in any language should be able to access your services.

Comment: Well, we are building an API, but I am talking specifically about the console application (we are looking to develop in Mono to do cross-platform).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the current AWS SDK for .NET (v2.2.4.0) appears to work in Mono 3.4.1.  AWS SDK didn't work in Mono 3.2.8.

I haven't done exhaustive testing, but a test app that runs a few queries against a DynamoDB table now works in Mono 3.4.1 running on Ubuntu 14. So, AWS authentication and request signing are now working on the Mono stack.  (The test app failed in Mono 3.2.8 with an "not implemented" exception in a token impersonation routine deep inside HttpClient webget as part of a call into the AWS SDK)

I'm using this Docker container as the mono execution environment: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/akoeplinger/mono-aspnetvnext/